# time difference returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I want to find a difference between 2 dates (or times, don't know how to say) in seconds.

here is the code:

```
var montharray = new Array ("Jan" , "Feb" , "Mar" , "Apr" , "May" , "Jun" , "Jul" , "Aug" , "Sept" , "Oct" , "Nov" , "Dec")
function time_difference (yr,m,d,h,mins,sec){
var today = new Date();
var this_year = today.getYear();
if (this_year<1000)
this_year+=1900;
var this_month= today.getMonth();
var this_day=today.getDate();
var this_hour=today.getHours();
var this_mins=today.getMinutes();
var this_secs=today.getSeconds();
var today_string=montharray[this_month]+" "+this_day+", "+this_year+" "+this_hour+" "+this_mins+" "+this_secs;
var disconnect_string=montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+h+" "+mins+" "+sec;
var difference=(Math.round((Date.parse(disconnect_string)-Date.parse(today_string))/1000)*1)
alert(difference);
    }
time_difference(2014,4,13,16,0,0)
```

(in my country, when I asked the question time was 15:26)

but alert shows me NaN.

BUT when I use only year, month, date it returns expected result, 1.

Is something wrong with punctuation or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JSFiddle is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/T2VV2/2/
I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

```
function time_difference (yr,m,d,h,mins,sec){

var t1 = new Date(yr,m-1,d,h,mins,sec);
var t2 = Date.now();
var diff_msec = t1 - t2;
var diff_seconds = parseInt(diff_msec/1000);
var diff_minutes = parseInt(diff_seconds/60);
var diff_hours = parseInt(diff_minutes/60);

alert(diff_seconds+" seconds");
alert(diff_minutes+" minutes");
alert(diff_hours+" hours");

}
time_difference(2014,4,13,16,0,0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks man, that helped! and it is probably the easiest way to do what I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `getTime`. It returns the date's UNIX offset in milliseconds.

```
var date1= new Date();
var date2 = new Date("2013-01-01");

var difference = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / 1000;
```

If you do not know which of the two dates is earlier, you can use `Math.abs` on the result.

```
difference = Math.abs(difference);
```

Comment: But what if i know exact h, mins and secs of date2?

Comment: This is just an example. You can construct a date with as much granularity as needed, e.g. `new Date("Sat Apr 12 2014 14:42:41 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)")`